# how to get length of wav file in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I jwant to get length of wave file. Currently I'm using following code

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isofile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isostream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(FilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open,System.IO.FileAccess.Read, isofile))
    {
        me = new MediaElement();
        me.SetSource(isostream);
    }
 }
embedVoiceLength = me.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
```

However, it doesn't return the length from `naturalduration.timespan.totalseconds` , because `me` is not opened;

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the length until the file is opened then try opening it.
If all you want is the length and to not actually play it then handle the `MediaOpened` event and when it is triggered get the length and then stop the playback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
Microphone microphone = Microphone.Default;

using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    TimeSpan duration = microphone.GetSampleDuration((int)stream.Length);
}
```

I picked this sample code from an interesting article on working with audio on WP7. [Here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mag201102UIFrontiers) it is, code is also available for download. Hope this helps! :)